# Compute the eccentricity, diameter, radius and center (with Java Code)

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

I'm currently stumped on where to start on a homework assignment.  Basically, we have been given a function and some Breadth First Search code.  The goal is to compute the things listed above, and he highly suggested using the BFS code to get there.  Any help at all is appreciated:

```
package algs41;

import stdlib.*;

// This is problem 4.1.16 from the textbook
//
// You need only change the constructor.
// You can also change the main method.
// But you should not change eccentricity(), diameter(), radius(), center() or isCenter()
// You can (and should!) add more private methods (such as bfs or dfs)
public class MyGraphProperties {
    int[] eccentricity;
    int diameter;
    int radius;
    int center; 

    // Constructor can be linear in G.V() * G.E()
    public MyGraphProperties(Graph G) {
        this.eccentricity = new int[G.V()];
        int diameter = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int radius = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int center = -1;
        // If G.V()==0, then these are the correct values.
        // If G is not connected, you should throw a new IllegalArgumentException()
        // I suggest that you first get it to work for a connected graph
        // This will require that you traverse the graph starting from some node (say 0)
        // You can then adjust your code so that it throws an exception in the case that all nodes are not visited

        // TODO
        // compute the eccentricity, diameter, radius and center
        // The center of the graph is not unique, set center to SOME center --- it does not matter which one
        this.diameter = diameter;
        this.radius   = radius;
        this.center   = center;
    }

    // Do not change the following constant time methods
    public int eccentricity(int v) { return eccentricity[v]; }
    public int diameter()          { return diameter; }
    public int radius()            { return radius; }
    public int center()            { return center; }
    public boolean isCenter(int v) { return eccentricity[v] == radius; }
```

**Here is the Relevant BFS Code:**

```
    private void bfs(Graph G, int s) {
        Queue<Integer> q = new Queue<>();
        for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++) distTo[v] = INFINITY;
        distTo[s] = 0;
        marked[s] = true;
        q.enqueue(s);

        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            int v = q.dequeue();
            for (int w : G.adj(v)) {
                if (!marked[w]) {
                    edgeTo[w] = v;
                    distTo[w] = distTo[v] + 1;
                    marked[w] = true;
                    q.enqueue(w);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Some things (such as distTo) do not exist at the moment.  That is due to use not being allowed to use the BreadthFirstSearch class that we were given, but we are allowed to copy and past the relevant code for our own use.  **Please edit the bfs void as little as possible.  According to the professor, the bfs I have given is all we need**  I am not really sure where to start, as stated above.  Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:  Added graph code**

```
public class Graph {
private final int V;
private int E;
private final Bag<Integer>[] adj;

/**
 * Create an empty graph with V vertices.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Graph(int V) {
    if (V < 0) throw new Error("Number of vertices must be nonnegative");
    this.V = V;
    this.E = 0;
    this.adj = new Bag[V];
    for (int v = 0; v < V; v++) {
        adj[v] = new Bag<>();
    }
}

/**
 * Create a random graph with V vertices and E edges with no parallel edges or self loops.
 * Expected running time is proportional to V + E.
 */
public Graph(int V, int E) { this (V, E, false); }
/**
 * Create a random graph with V vertices and E edges.
 * Expected running time is proportional to V + E.
 */
public Graph(int V, int E, boolean allowParallelEdgesAndSelfLoops) {
    this(V);
    if (E < 0) throw new Error("Number of edges must be nonnegative");
    if (allowParallelEdgesAndSelfLoops) {
        for (int i = 0; i < E; i++) {
            int v = (int) (Math.random() * V);
            int w = (int) (Math.random() * V);
            addEdge(v, w);
        }
    } else {
        if (E > V*(V-1)/2) throw new Error("Number of edges must be less than V*(V-1)/2");
        newEdge: while (E>0) {
            int v = (int) (Math.random() * V);
            int w = (int) (Math.random() * V);
            if (v == w) continue;
            for (int w2 : adj[v])
                if (w == w2)
                    continue newEdge;
            addEdge(v, w);
            E--;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Create a digraph from input stream.
 */
public Graph(In in) {
    this(in.readInt());
    int E = in.readInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < E; i++) {
        int v = in.readInt();
        int w = in.readInt();
        addEdge(v, w);
    }
}

/**
 * Copy constructor.
 */
public Graph(Graph G) {
    this(G.V());
    this.E = G.E();
    for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++) {
        // reverse so that adjacency list is in same order as original
        Stack<Integer> reverse = new Stack<>();
        for (int w : G.adj[v]) {
            reverse.push(w);
        }
        for (int w : reverse) {
            adj[v].add(w);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Return the number of vertices in the graph.
 */
public int V() { return V; }

/**
 * Return the number of edges in the graph.
 */
public int E() { return E; }


/**
 * Add the undirected edge v-w to graph.
 * @throws java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException unless both 0 <= v < V and 0 <= w < V
 */
public void addEdge(int v, int w) {
    if (v < 0 || v >= V) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    if (w < 0 || w >= V) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    E++;
    adj[v].add(w);
    adj[w].add(v);
}


/**
 * Return the list of neighbors of vertex v as in Iterable.
 * @throws java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException unless 0 <= v < V
 */
public Iterable<Integer> adj(int v) {
    if (v < 0 || v >= V) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    return adj[v];
}
```

[image]

Comment: My suggestion would be to copy his BFS code, get some output and then start to implement other algorithms, like DFS.

Comment: Can we see the Graph class?

Comment: Done, sorry about that.